# How to host Next JS built index.html separately from other static assets?

Tags: next.js, static, single-page-application, assets

I have a Next JS SPA (no server-side code), which after `next build` produces `index.html` along with other static assets (JS chunks, images etc.) in the `_next` folder as usual. See image below for the folder structure.

[image: build folder structure]

I need to render this SPA during a particular flow of a commercial product. Due to constraints of that environment, I must host the `index.html` on that environment but must host the other static assets elsewhere (e.g. a public S3 bucket)

Will this kind of a setup work just by changing all *relative paths* inside `index.html` to *absolute paths* pointing to the static assets?

For e.g.

Original relative URL in `index.html`:

```
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/961-e6437325a155ddfa.js" async=""></script>
```

Manually rewritten absolute URL:

```
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-public-bucket/_next/static/chunks/961-e6437325a155ddfa.js" async=""></script>
```

If not, how to make this kind of a distributed setup work?

Comment: I would have the host that handle the index.html to also do the rewrite to S3 for any other file, or having a proxy in front of it to achieve that.
That's kinda the point of middlewares.

Comment: Thanks @EricBurel - unfortunately the server hosting `index.html` cannot perform URL rewrites. Will the manual rewrite approach above not work? (I am concerned that there may be many relative URLs within the cryptic code inside the chunks as well which may probably be impossible / very hard to manually rewrite).

Comment: I honestly suggest to reassess your infrastructure, I often see people trying to achieve dynamic use cases with a totally static server: ditch the server, not your use case. A big regex on generated chunks will probably work, but a proxy server will make you architecture much more resilient. A regex on the generated chunks will probably works yes but that doesn't sound extra reliable, eg if an URL ends up being generated at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the Vercel engineer who pointed me to this config:

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
 
module.exports = {
  // Use the CDN in production and localhost for development.
  assetPrefix: isProd ? 'https://cdn.mydomain.com' : undefined,
}
```

Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/assetPrefix